# Integration in PID controller

Tags: integration, control-theory

I am trying to understand how come there is a phase difference is from the error signal and the output of my PID controller which consisting of I  = 1.

As far i've understood should the integration return the area of the graph the error signal gives, but for some reason does not make sense when i simulate it in matlab. It seems to me that area keep growing in different rates, it looks to be offset by the step, and never goes below 0 (subtraction of area. ).

[image: Blue line = PID Output => integral , RED = step with 10, Yellow = Error signal(input for PID), Purple = output of closed loop system]

The System itself looks like this P = 1 , and I = 1.
[image]

Comment: The primary reason is that a PID loop is iterative:  the magnitude of the error is applied in the opposite direction to the output signal (with a constant multiple to regulate effect), and it is the prior iteration that provides the current output adjustment.

Comment: A pure-proportional loop will nearly match the area of error, but too large a proportion will increase the error, while a proportion that is too small will make the response of the loop too slow.

Comment: To be more specific, i don't how the SSE get towards zero, and how  the offset becomes the step I place??.

Comment: What does SSE mean in this context?

Comment: steady state error.

Comment: As in my answer, the steady state error is created by the proportional constant.  The integral portion is then added in to the output signal as an "extra" and this adding brings the error towards zero.  With too much integral, the error will overshoot and the loop will not approach steady-state.  This is also called "integral wind-up", where the amount of the output signal supplied by the integral becomes a larger and larger portion of the overall signal.

Comment: When a PI loop reaches steady-state of zero, the proportional part of the output will be smaller than if the loop was solely-proportional, and the integral portion will be the remainder.

Comment: Your system looks reasonable for finding the steady-state of the function $1\over s^2+10s+1$.

Answer (score 2):

When a PID loop has an error between set point and input signals, that error is used directly in the proportional and integral portions of the loop.  In particular, as long as the error is negative, the integral will be applying its effect in the positive direction; not until the error is positive will the integral switch and apply its effect in the negative direction.

The terms "integral," "proportional" and "derivative" speak exactly to the mathematical properties of these respective parts of the loop.  In particular, if the error is an exact sine wave, the proportional will match with an in-phase sine wave.  The integral of a sine wave is another sine wave that is phase-shifted, and similarly with the derivative, so graphing all of these together will show two in-phase sine waves, and two other sine waves in other phases, one "before" and the other "after" the error phase.

When a loop is applied in a manner which would decrease the error over time, the effect of the proportional term is to bring the error term to a constant state - not necessarily zero.  The effect of the integral term is to push the error term towards zero - push too hard and overshoot occurs.  The effect of the derivative term is to push the error away from zero - this counteracts integral overshoot, but can also prevent steady-state operation.

Taking the system you have, notice that the proportional (in yellow) exactly mirrors the error (in purple), while the integral (in blue) is also mirrored and $\pi\over 2$ behind in phase from the error.  Further, it is clear that as the integral part works to reduce the difference between the total output and the error, the proportional part of the output converges to $0$ while the integral part converges to match the input (in red).  The total output is $100$% integral at $t=\infty$ since the proportional part has gone to $0$.

Comment: I understand why phase shift appears(when the Error passes zero the integration change direction), but i am not quite sure about how the offset mathmatically becomes  equal to the offset we apply the system. 

And about zero SSE,  i read somewhere that the I Part will lead it towards zero.  Yes The P part make it appear, but i don't understand how the integration pull it towards zero.

Comment: It depends on whether the I is applied in the correct direction as well.  If the I is applied in the wrong direction, it will add its portion to the output and increase the error, all the way to the upper or lower limit of the loop.

Comment: The Integral receives an input which is  E(s) = input(s) - output(s).  So I don't see how it should be incorrect. 
Shouldn't there normally be somekind of offset??

Comment: I don't understand this question about the offset.  What would make the formula correct or incorrect?  Also, typically there is some in-between data where the output alters the environment that results in the input, rather than feeding the output immediately back into the loop as the setpoint...

Comment: I've added my system . 
About the in - between, I am not quite sure, since my feedback is 1.

Comment: So your PID loop is reading from the $+-$ circle which reads Step2 and the transfer function.  These are the "in-between" that make up the environment which receives the output of the PID and creates the input value for the PID.  Specifically, it appears that the transfer function is the main adjustment for how the output relates to the input.

Comment: Yes.. I don't know if i've missed it, but why the offset appears is still a bit unclear??.

Comment: Should I become 0 as t goes towards ∞

Comment: No, $I$ would tend toward some constant so that the integral portion of the output takes over in place of the proportional part of the output.  This difference or offset is what makes the loop approach a steady state of $E=0$ rather than $E=c$ for some constant under a proportion-only loop.  Or rather, the integral portion of the output would tend towards a constant, obviously $I=1$ by your specified system.

Comment: The part that confuses is when the system output is 10, and the  output of the in betweens is 10 - 10 = 0, how come would the PID part still output 10, since the error signal (input for PID)...

Comment: The PID must output $10$ to make the error $0$.  Have you simulated what happens with this system when $I=0$ and $P=1$?  How about $I=0.5, 2$, etc.?

Comment: but how come is it possible for the PID to output  10, when it's input is 0.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14499/discussion-between-abiessu-and-control)

Comment: Low rep to continue in chat..
If i set I = 0, i get a huge steady state error of sse = 5.